# IBM ContentManager v8 - Query Syntax to search documents by its creation date

Tags: java, db2-content-manager

We are using IBM ContentManager v8. I am looking for the correct syntax to find all documents uploaded to CM, after a specific date.    I would like to use the document or object creation time stamp, which is an internal attribute of every document uploaded to CM.

Our backend database for CM is DB2.

From the example, I see that we can use 
/<item_type> [ICMCHECKEDOUT/@ICMCHKOUTTS > "2013-11-20-12.00.00.000000"] 
for example, to find all documents that were checked out after the specified date.

Is there an internal attribute for the time on which the object was added to CM.?  If yes, what is the syntax.?

FYI:-  DKLobICM.getCreatedTimestamp() method returns the exact time the object was added to CM. But I need a way to use this timestamp in my query.

Rgds,
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

`/<item_type>[@SYSROOTATTRS.CREATETS>"2013-11-20-12.00.00.000000"]`

will give you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  /<item_type>[@AttributeRef="xxxxx" AND @CREATETS BETWEEN "2015-06-01-00.00.00.000" AND "2015-12-31-00.00.00.0000"]
```